# jQuery: vw instead of px

Tags: jquery, pixel, viewport

Any idea how to convert the 100px into 100vw?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function() { 
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 100) { 
      $(".header").css("color", "#fff"); 
    } else {
      $(".header").css("color", "#000"); 
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the viewport width with this line of code:

```
const width = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth || 0, window.innerWidth || 0);
```

then use the variable in your code as in this example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  const width = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth || 0, window.innerWidth || 0);
  $(window).scroll(function() { 
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > width) { 
      $(".header").css("color", "#fff"); 
    } else {
      $(".header").css("color", "#000"); 
    }
  });
});
```

Note that you are referring to `scrollTop` so you probably want to get the vh, in this case you can use this other line of code:

```
const height = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight || 0, window.innerHeight || 0);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Emanuele. Unfortunately this doesn't work for me and I have no clue why.